# undefined method total_pages' for array will_paginate rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have added gem '`will_paginate`' and gem '`will_paginate-bootstrap`' to my app, and it  works fine. However I do get this error message due to RSpec test.

```
Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `total_pages' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8c238a97b8>
```

This is the Rspec code:

```
 it "renders a list of users" do
    render

    page = Capybara::Node::Simple.new(rendered)

    expect(page).to have_content("Smith, Agent admin@somewhere.com Site Admin")
    expect(page).to have_content("Johnson, Bob manager.email@elsewhere.com The Company Name")
  end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def index
    @per_page = params[:per_page] || 10
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @per_page).order('last_name  ASC')
end
```

The index.html.erb

```
<div class="pull-right">
  Records per page
  <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,25,50,100], params[:per_page].to_i),
       :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>
</div>

<%= page_entries_info @users %>

<br>
<div class="pull-right">
  <%= will_paginate @users, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but why do you define @users twice in your index action?

Comment: Hi Max, I actually too it out now. : ) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Rspec >= 3, try the below:

```
 it "renders a list of users" do
    allow(view).to receive_messages(:will_paginate => nil) # Add this

    render

    page = Capybara::Node::Simple.new(rendered)

    expect(page).to have_content("Smith, Agent admin@somewhere.com Site Admin")
    expect(page).to have_content("Johnson, Bob manager.email@elsewhere.com The Company Name")
  end
```

Comment: Based on this answer, I used `view.stub :will_paginate` and it worked on Rspec 2.14.

Comment: I was getting `undefined method 'total_pages' for #<Array...` for my view spec, but the above fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Use Kaminari helper

---

```
RSpec.describe 'rendering view', type: :view do

  let(:posts) do
    Kaminari.paginate_array(create_list(:post, 10)).page(1)
  end

  it 'displays posts' do
    # assign(:posts, posts) # if it's instance variable
    render partial: '/post_list.html.erb', :locals => {:posts => posts }
  end

end
```